# how to draw line (route) in android google map acoording to passed coordinates

Tags: android, google-maps

Good coding to everyone,

My situation is this;

for example i have coordinates, lets say they are Q,W,E,R,T,Y,U.

I want show this route in google map with PolylineOptions. It's ok but how can i show passed coordinates on real time.

For instance; Q-W-E-R-T-Y-U is the route and showing with blue line. When I come the "R" ;Q-W-E must be shown with grey(different) line. And this must be real time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lat of searching, i recognized this methodology. I dont like , but it works. Everytime (current coordinate changed), i recall my metot.

The metot is above;

```
public void add(GoogleMap mGoogleMap) {
    PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true);
    for (int z = 0; z < list.size(); z++) {
        LatLng point = list.get(z);
        options.add(point);
    }
    mGoogleMap.addPolyline(options);
}
```

Everytime, somewhere in code i added LatLng to Arraylist (in code list) and recall this method. And this will be real time tracking. Any other specifications can be done now.

But i dont like this logic, if there will be any other solutions, please write.

=)

Answer (score 0):

Using [PolylineOptions](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/PolylineOptions) you can achieve that.

First save the color's in XML file `color.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
    <color name="yellow">#FFFF00</color>
    <color name="green">#00FF00</color>
    <color name="cyan">#00FFFF</color>
    <color name="blue">#0000FF</color>
    <color name="magenta">#FF00FF</color>

    <array name="colors">
        <item>@color/red</item>
        <item>@color/yellow</item>
        <item>@color/green</item>
        <item>@color/cyan</item>
        <item>@color/blue</item>
        <item>@color/magenta</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

Create a Latlong object of Q,W,E,R,T,Y,U and save it into a `List` then pass it into a PolylineOptions like this.

```
 int[] polyColor= context.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.colors);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                LatLng latPoint = list.get(i);
                googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                .add(latPoint)
                .width(5)
                .color(polyColor[i]));
            }
```

make sure you have more colors than latlong :)

Comment: Thank you for your effort but I already did that. Drawing before is not the problem. Problem is how can do that real time ? User moves the land, and the screen colored footprint with different color.

Comment: @Arda just update the latlong list and when you reach 'R' a new point;  call the last part of the code which is written in the answer. I do the same :)